# Flutter horizontal gridview snap scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need flutter snap effect.
How to create?

[image]

Comment: you can read this bloc : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliverappbar-snap-those-headers-544e097248c0

Comment: I need gridview snap. not appbar

Answer (score 0):

Try PageView.builder

```
PageView.builder(
itemCount: 10,
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
   return Column(
    children: [
      Card(
       backgroundColor: Colors.yellow
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Card(
       backgroundColor: Colors.yellow
      ),
    ],
  );
 }
)
```

Comment: Modify the code based on your needs

Comment: I need for gridview

Answer (score 0):

Try `GridView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to get a grid with horizontal scroll just like you need.
Refer to the below example.

```
   GridView.count(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      crossAxisSpacing: 6,
      children: List.generate(
        30,
        (index) => Text('I am text$index'),
      ),
    )
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I need snap effect